# How to use SelectedIndexChanged-Event of ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, combobox

I have a ComboBox with two read only values: white fusion and silver fusion.
How do I get the correct method to run based on selecting each one in a ComboBox? The methods are just pulling an Integer from a SQL table and put it into a TextBox.

```
private void cboOilVehicle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cboVehicle.SelectedIndexChanged == "White Fusion")
    {
        whiteFusionOil();
    }
    else
    {
        silverFusionOil();    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
private void cboOilVehicle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (cboVehicle.SelectedIndex == 0)
  {
    whiteFusionOil();
  }
  else
  {
    silverFusionOil();    
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

The name of the control must be `cboOilVehicle` (Line 1) or `cboVehicle` (Line 3), it can't be both. You have to decide which is correct

Comment: That only allows for one change. How can I make it so I can keep changing back and forth? Thanks

Comment: Why does this work only for one change? There is nothing in there, that could have this effect. Look at whiteFusionOil() and silverFusionOil() for the culprit

Comment: private void whiteFusionOil()
{
using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
var car = (from c in db.cars
where c.carDesc == "White Fusion"
select c.oilChange).FirstOrDefault();
txtOilChange.Text = car.ToString();
}
}

Comment: That is one of the two methods which are identical besides the where clause. As soon as I change the combo box it changes once and then its done

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to be comparing the text directly, use the `Text` property of the combobox:

```
private void cboOilVehicle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cboVehicle.Text == "White Fusion")
    {
        whiteFusionOil();
    } 
    else
    {
        silverFusionOil();    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below

```
if(cboVehicle.SelectedItem.Text == "White Fusion")
{

whiteFusionOil();

}
else 
{
silverFusionOil();

}
```